# How to implement to restore the last saved or opened instance or page for a windows application in case of crashed?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, legacy-code

I wanted to implement one of my idea where I want to restore or open the saved pages again of the last instance for a window application in case of crashed or sudden shut down.

The current approach, as we have to re-configured all the steps and actions as we have done before crashing.

Background - We have a WPF windows application with C# and legacy code.

Suggest me any suggestion or way to achieve this.

Comment: Rather depends how much data you need to reconstruct where they were.  At one end of the scale you might need a whole tree of data. At the other you might just need to know which view and parameters for that. Serialise away whatever you need. Do that on view load.  Maybe keep the last so many views worth. Last 10 or some such. 
Then give em a button says load last view. When they click that you deserialise that data you saved away and use it to build the viewmodel(s), present the view.

Comment: You would have to serialize the data model of the page (e.g. to JSON) to persist its state. Additionally write to a second file e.g. a simple boolean flag, to indicate that the application has previously crashed. Read this flag on application initialization to know whether to restore the last session (or ask the user). When loaded simply deserialize the page's data model and clear the crash-flag.

Comment: You won't be notified (in code) when a crash happens, so you can not execute some code to save the "current open pages" to restore them at the next launch. 

I think you can just create your own `UINavigationTracer` to log the navigation events on an external file.. If the app shuts down normally -> ignore these logs at the next launch, otherwise, read the logs to restore the last open 'pages'.

Comment: Actually... you could be notified in code when an unhandled error happens. For many errors but not all. Stack overflow is particularly deadly and you're not going to be able to guarantee trapping and handling it gracefully.

Comment: Oh... Forgot to clarify something.  I suggested the last so many views because a user might conceivably have to go several steps back to avoid some sort of predictable error.